# How to load the data in table in mysql into cloudera(launched using virtual box)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cloudera

I have a web application accessed using WAMP server which asks user for his current location and gets his latitude and longitude.

These latitude and longitude values gets stored in a table in mysql database.

Now I need to work on this latitude and longitude values to give the user his/her nearest location.

So I want to import these latitude and longitude values in mysql database into hadoop.

I installed cloudera and launched it using virtual box. 
Now in cloudera command prompt when I try to import the values in mysql table using a query like this

```
$ bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.1/testDb --table latlog --username root -P -m 1
```

where testDb is my database name and latlog is my table name

It is showing error like this:

> Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How to load the table in mysql database in our local machine to hadoop in virtual machine (cloudera)?

I tried so many solutions provided in web but could not resolve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: username and password you are passing to command dosent match. Please provide the correct one.

Comment: Yes i can see that but it seems your entering the wrong one.

Comment: no because when i tried the same credentials to open mysql in command prompt(admin) it worked.but when i try to access mysql from cloudera cmd it is giving the above error

Comment: Have you granted the permission for you user.

Comment: yes i did that using grant all privileges query

Answer (score 0):

The stepwise process to import data from MySQL to Cloudera VM is as follows:

1. Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar and keep that in Desktop of                Cloudera
2. Copy this jar file into sqoop library using command

   sudo cp /home/cloudera/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib
3. Now change your current working directory to sqoop using command `cd /usr/lib/sqoop`
4. Open command prompt as Administrator in your system and know the IPV4 address of your system by running `ipconfig` command eg:192.168.56.1
5. Now in your MySQL issue all permissions using the command

   grant all privileges on *.* to root@192.168.56.1 IDENTIFIED BY ‘root’ WITH GRANT OPTION;
6. Now in cloudera command line give this command for importing data `bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.1/testDb --table latlog --username root -P -m 1`
   where testDb is database name, latlog is table name. Then it asks for password.Type root as password. Now data gets imported from MySQL to cloudera(Hadoop) using Sqoop
7. To view the imported data give command

   hadoop dfs -ls -R latlog

   and it shows the file where imported data is stored. To view the contents in that file give command

   hadoop dfs -cat latlog/part-m-00000

   which prints all the data in latlog table.

   Thanks..